# How can I setup a cell and collective in Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty, ibm-was-oc

I'm trying to setup a cell and a collective in a WAS for bluemix service.  I've found a few steps online for generic liberty setup, but nothing specific for a bluemix collective or cell.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a high level, you should be able to do the following for a Cell:

1. Login to the Admin Console as wsadmin
2. Create a server.
3. Open all the ports on each host for each server created by running the openFirewallPorts.sh script.  Below, you will find the standard ports for a new server given that only one server exists on each host  You may need to open more ports for additional servers on the same host since ports can be unique per server. Try the following:

   ```
   cd WAS_HOME/virtual/bin

   export serverPorts=2810:TCP,2810:UDP,8880:TCP,8880:UDP,9101:TCP,9101:UDP,9061:TCP,9061:UDP,9080:TCP,9080:UDP,9354:TCP,9354:UDP,9044:TCP,9044:UDP,9443:TCP,9443:UDP,5060:TCP,5060:UDP,5061:TCP,5061:UDP,11005:TCP,11005:UDP,11007:TCP,11007:UDP,9633:TCP,9633:UDP,7276:TCP,7276:UDP,7286:TCP,7286:UDP,5558:TCP,5558:UDP,5578:TCP,5578:UDP

   sudo ./openFirewallPorts.sh -ports $serverPorts -persist true
   ```
4. Start your server.
5. Deploy your application.

---

There are a few slight differences for a Liberty Collective, but again, at a high level, you should be able to try the following:

1. Switch your user to wsadmin or ssh to your host using wsadmin / password
2. On each host, create a server and join it to the collective.  Be sure to use the full host name of the controller for the --host parameter.

   ```
   cd WAS_HOME/bin

   ./server create server

   ./collective join server --host=yourhostname --port=9443 --user=wsadmin --password=xxxxxxxx --keystorePassword=yyyyyyyy

   Accept the chain certificate (y/n) y
   ```

Save the output from each join so you can paste it into each host's application server.xml file before deploying your application.

3. Install the features required by your application on each host.  The features listed below are an example.

   ```
   cd /opt/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/bin

   ./featureManager install --acceptLicense ejblite-3.2 websocket-1.0 jsp-2.3 jdbc-4.1 jaxrs-2.0 cdi-1.2 beanValidation-1.1
   ```

**NOTE:** Output from this command will contain messages similar to:

> chmod: changing permissions of
>   `/opt/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/bin/featureManager': Operation not
>   permitted

This is OK.  You should see this message upon completion:

> Product validation completed successfully.

4. Update your application's server.xml file with the information saved in Step 2.
5. Start your server.
6. Deploy your application.
7. Verify your application is reachable :9080/appname

Comment: Thanks.  Didn't know about the script to open the ports on the firewall.  Useful!