# How do I configure a webserver for a collective in Bluemix?

Tags: ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty, ibmhttpserver, ibm-was-oc

I found doc that indicates I need to setup a webserver in my collective environment, however, I cannot determine the correct set of steps.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

It would help to see what you've already tried, but consider the following:

1. Create two or more servers on one or more of the hosts and join them to the collective.  Make sure your servers are clusterMembers and collectiveMembers. The following post should help with creating servers and joining them to the collective:
   [How can I setup a cell and collective in Bluemix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366573/how-can-i-setup-a-cell-and-collective-in-bluemix)
2. Update the controller's `/etc/hosts` file with the hostnames of all the hosts in the collective.
3. Download and follow this guide to generate the plugin-cfg.xml file on the controller:
   https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/scripts-jython-Generate_Cluster_Plugin
4. Copy the generated `plugin-cfg.xml` file to `/opt/IBM/WebSphere/HTTPServer/conf`
5. Edit `/opt/IBM/WebSphere/HTTPServer/conf/httpd.conf` and uncomment these two lines at the bottom of the file:

   ```
   LoadModule was_ap22_module /opt/IBM/WebSphere/Plugins/bin/64bits/mod_was_ap22_http.so
   WebSpherePluginConfig /opt/IBM/WebSphere/Profiles/Liberty/servers/controller/pluginConfig/myLibertyCluster-plugin-cfg.xml
   ```
6. Change the `WebSpherePluginConfig` value to be `/opt/IBM/WebSphere/HTTPServer/conf/plugin-cfg.xml`
7. Stop and start the HTTP server

   ```
   sudo ./apachectl stop
   sudo ./apachectl start
   ```
8. Verify the application can be reached using the webserver `<webserverIP>:80/appname`
9. Generate the plugin again if the application is added or removed.